# What does the output of NSLog exactly mean?

Tags: objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NSLog 10b meaning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428544/nslog-10b-meaning)

I am new to objc and iOS development. And, I have a question about `NSLog`. As we know, `NSLog` will log message like this:

> 2011-07-16 23:19:35.467 HelloWorld[11166:7c37] say hello to iOS.

Obviously the format is `date time ProjectName`, but what does the `[11166:7c37]` part mean?

Comment: have a look to : [NSLog 10b meaning?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428544/nslog-10b-meaning)

Comment: Nice observation; but what you want to achieve by knowing this?

Comment: @Waqas Raja: it is apparently output for a reason, so it is, IMO, legitimite to ask what that reason is.

Comment: Just looked to the post, of course it's process id and thread id! Thank you!

Comment: @Waqas Raja I just want to know what it is, because I think it should be some useful message if it is putted there by default.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its a process / thread ID I believe.