# What is the significance of the number in [xx] after the project name in XCode build console

Tags: xcode

When I compile my app, you get the usual

```
2014-02-11 14:25:15.752 LNG[23078:60b]
```

What does [23078:60b] mean?

Useless question, but I was just wondering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSLogv)

> The message consists of a timestamp and the process ID prefixed to the string you pass in.

- `23078` will be the process ID on your mac
- `60b` is the thread ID

SEE ALSO: [NSLog 10b meaning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428544/nslog-10b-meaning)

Comment: thats rather useless then imo. Thanks anyway. Didn't know what to google.

Comment: You might be interested in reading some of these https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=a+better+NSLog