# iOS : Determine code based on console log

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, console

I'm getting a console log `'Pin's dont match'` (in this case). I've searched throughout project but **didn't find any**.

[image: Screenshot 0]

This may be generated by use of third party framework. **By reading console how can I recoginse where the print() statment is?**

There is pattern `AppName[1234:1234334]` printed on console. So, here the what does first and second value in square bracket mean?

[image: Screenshot 1]

Comment: Are you 100% you searched with the EXACT text?  Your text above says "dont" without an apostrophe, so if you used that, it might not find it.  I would also try substrings of the message, like just "don't match" because Pin could be a substitution.

Comment: Does Pin mean something in your app -- are you using MapKit?

Comment: @LouFranco : Yes checked it throughly.. Ignoring case enabled..

Comment: @LouFranco : Check updated question.

Comment: "Please provide new" ????? new WHAT?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428544/nslog-10b-meaning (for the meaning of the `[3187:1214969]`)

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your Breakpoint navigator in XCode (⌘7)
2. Add a symbolic breakpoint (little plus down in the bottom left of the navigator)
3. Type in the symbol: "NSLog" (other fields can be left empty)
4. Run your application

If it doesn't work you can try for Swift.print and print commands that might also log to your console.